# How to import content in markdown format?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, feeds, input-formats

I have text in markdown format. How should I go about importing this into my site? I would think a Feeds Tamper plugin to convert markdown to html would be ideal.

Does such a thing exist? Is there a straightforward way to convert markdown to html in Drupal?

Comment: Did you search for drupal modules and markdown in Google? Feeds and https://www.drupal.org/project/markdown is 1 simple solution.

Comment: Yes, that looks great, but as I understand it that project is an input filter. I didn't want the markdown to stay in markdown format, but I guess that is a solution as you say.

Comment: I see, no you'd have to write code for either Feeds or Migrate to pre-process the markdown to html.

Comment: @tenken Thanks for your help in clearing up this issue. I will re-evaluate my strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why complicate things by importing markdown? If html format is what is desired, there are many options to convert it beforehand. For example this simple [python implementation](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2).

As tenken suggested, [Markdown filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/markdown) is an option to consider.